How do I connect an LED with two cathodes and two anodes?
I came across an LED that has two terminals, cathode and anode. My project is a board with 38 infrared LEDs in an MCPCB that I need to design. In this case, I would like to use two 21V supplies to power the entire circuit.

How can I do this with this type of LED?
Can I connect one source to one cathode and another to the other?
Can I also connect the cathodes together and the anodes together and connect these LEDs in series or parallel as if they were normal LEDs?


Source: OSRAM LZ1-00R702 datasheet from Mouser website

It's still just a two-terminal device. The two cathode pins are physically connected internally, as are the two anode pins.

Why / how do you want to use the two power supplies?  For some sort of redundancy or just higher total capacity?  Then pins are connected internally, generally they should be connected together externally so that current can balance between them.

Can I connect one source to one cathode and another to the other? ... there is only one cathode ... it happens to have two wires connected to it

The pins are internally connected, one might guess from the datasheet that they are connected via two wire bonds.
It may not be ideal to use the wire bonds as jumpers - normally you would just connect the pins together 1-4 and 2-3 on the PCB. If you're concerned about that constraining the layout on a one-layer metal core PCB that may not be what you want though.
I don't see any recommendations in the (mostly thermal) application note.  If you're planning on using the internal connections as jumpers it might be worth asking the question of the supplier. It's probably okay, but..

the pins 1 and 4 are just two extensions of the cathode. similarly, pins 2 and 3 are extensions of anode. you can just use it as a normal LED.
